# Directory path of images for waterfall jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, path, waterfall

I'm using the jquery WATERFALL plugin.  I would like the script to display all of the images from a folder rather than using JSON data files.  Is this possible?

```
<script>
$('#container').waterfall({
itemCls: 'item',
colWidth: 222,
gutterWidth: 15,
gutterHeight: 15,
checkImagesLoaded: false,
isAnimated: true,
animationOptions: {
},
path: function(page) {
    return 'data/data1.json?page=' + page;
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, no, for security reasons JavaScript has no access to the FileSystem on the browser environment. I'd suggest reading the directory on the server side. Then you can JSON encode the result and send it to the client side.